# URL path with universal header is not working

Tags: php, html

I have three pages on my localhost 1 is my index page,2 is my universal header page which is under includes folder of and 3 is my html file which is under html folder.The header file is included in both the index file and html file like that...
for index.php-include("includes/header.php");
for html.php-include("../includes/header.php");

and my header has the link of index.php page that is (./index.php)

Now my questions is that when i open my index page and click on link of index page from my header it takes me to same index.php page but when in open html.php page and then click index.php page link from header it does not go to index.php page but it goes to this page-
(localhost/educational%20website/html/index.php) how to solve that.

And i also want to know that write now i am on localhost but when i make my site live is there any need to change the paths because i am making around 150 pages with your technique plaese so please answer me that kind of technique that is used for both localhost and on live

Comment: instead of posting a description of your code, post your code

Comment: that title is off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are including paths relatively, use a (absolute) base path in your `index.php` to fix this:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php');
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no breakage of links when i live my website because at that time i have to change 150 to 200 pages and also want to know in this case what is my document_root and what is in live.

Comment: If you're not sure what the value of `DOCUMENT_ROOT` on your live system is, check it by using `print_r($_SERVER)`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define a variable or a constant for the site's url in the `header.php` file. Then in all your other pages, you could just use this variable/constant when you need to mention the other urls.

Eg(put this as first line in your header.php file):

```
define('SITE_URL', 'http://localhost/educationalwebsite');
```

Here, we have defined a constant named `SITE_URL`. Then in other pages, you are already including this header file. Isn't it? So, this constant will be available in your `index.php`, `html.php` and other pages.

And suppose for a link in your `html.php` file(to point to the `index.php`), you could use it like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL;?>/index.php">Home</a>
```

If you want to include link to the `html.php` file residing inside `html` folder, it would be like:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL;?>/html/html.php">HTML</a>
```

By using this way, if you are uploading the whole site to a live server, you only need to change one line, ie. the first line in `header.php`, where we have defined the `SITE_URL` constant. Just change it's value to the new URL of the home directory of your website.

Hope this helps